# I can't use sudo commands!

Tags: pantheon-terminal, sudo

When I go to terminal and try to enter a sudo commands it say's "Username not in the sudoers file." So how can I be able to use sudo commands.

Comment: Do you have any other users on the machine, or a password set for root?

Comment: Can you login as root by entering your password using `su -` command?

Comment: It asks for a password, I try mine but it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You need *some* user account with root priviledges to assign root priviledges to your own account.

To check if you have any such account on your computer you can either check:

a) Switchboard > User accounts

b) checking the content of sudoers file in /etc/sudoers. However I see no way of checking it without sudo other than booting from liveCD and opening it from there.

This is not exactly an answer and should have been a comment. However I don't have enough reputation points to comment your question so I've been forced to polute it with fake answer. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I think this is probably fine as a partial answer :) Someone else could build off this to create a more complete answer

Comment: I do have another account with root privileges. So how do I assign it to my account.

Comment: you need to log into the other account with root priviledges and either do the change via switchboard (I don't know if it's possible as I have just one account) or opening terminal (WinKey+T) and entering 'sudo adduser <your_username> sudo'

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue as the only administator of my machine. If you have another administative user, jena's answer is an easier way.

I was really helped by an anwser on askubuntu about resting a lost administrative password.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

### Full  steps :

You need to boot into recovery mode.

Boot up the machine, and *after* the BIOS screen, hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. You will then be prompted by a menu that looks something like this:

[image]

I've noticed on some systems that timing when to hit the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, sometimes I miss it and need to try it again.

If you have **full disk encryption**, you have to hold down the key **before** being asked for the disk password. (You will be asked for the password in a command line interface during boot).

Hit the down arrow until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you should see this menu:

[image]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

```
root@elementary:~#
```

At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Now we can set the user back into the sudoers group with the `adduser` command. (In this example I will use jorge as the example, you need to substitute whatever the user's username is):

```
root@elementary:~# adduser jorge sudo
```

Now you can reboot, and you should be able to use sudo commands. You should make sure that you are part of following groups :

- adm
- sudo
- lpadmin
- sambashare
- jorge (your username)

`jorge@elementary:~$ groups`

You can add your user back in these groups with sudo

`jorge@elementary:~$ sudo adduser jorge adm`

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved very easily by executing the following command in terminal

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```